# How to create exact duplicate of Django model that has M2M and FK relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model that already exists that I'd like to duplicate, and I can't figure out an easy way how because of related-name conflicts across `ForeignKey`s and `ManyToMany`s.

As an example, let's call the model I currently have `Dog`:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Owner')
    breeds = models.ManyToMany('myapp.Breed', help_text="Remember, animals can be mixed of multiple breeds.")
```

I'd like to make an exact duplicate of this model for use elsewhere, with a different database table and name.  I tried using an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
class AnimalAbstract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Owner')
    breeds = models.ManyToMany('myapp.Breed', help_text="Remember, animals can be mixed of multiple breeds.")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Dog(AnimalAbstract):
    pass

class Cat(AnimalAbstract):
    pass
```

This fails because of `related_name` conflicts.

Is there any way to automatically copy a model like this without explicitly redefining every `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany`?

*To preemptively answer questions: yes, I know about [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), and I don't want to use it.  I also know that I could simply store this all in the same table and use [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) with custom managers to automatically filter out the wrong type of animal, but I don't want that either—I want them on separate database tables.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name

To work around this problem, when you are using related_name in an abstract base class (only), part of the name should contain `%(app_label)s` and `%(class)s`.

- `%(class)s` is replaced by the lower-cased name of the child class that the field is used in.
- `%(app_label)s` is replaced by the lower-cased name of the app the child class is contained within. Each installed application name must be unique and the model class names within each app must also be unique, therefore the resulting name will end up being different.

Ex:

```
 class Dog(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     owner = models.ForeignKey(
         'myapp.Owner', 
         related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_dogs")

     breeds = models.ManyToMany(
         'myapp.Breed', 
         help_text="Remember, animals can be mixed of multiple breeds.", 
         related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_dogs")
```